# How can I turn on cgroup v2 CPU controller on modern Ubuntu?

Tags: cpu, cgroup, resource-limiting, cpulimit

On Ubuntu 22.04, I get:

```
# cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cgroup.controllers
cpuset memory hugetlb pids rdma misc
```

I really need `cpu` contoller. Could you, please, help on how to enable it?

Answer (score 0):

As explained here https://serverfault.com/a/931180/518713 an https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/635645/346609 I needed just to add cgroup_no_v1=all as a kernel boot option in my grub config and update grub, and reboot. And here it is. None legacy cpu is mounted as cgroup v1. So it becomes available for cgroup v2.